# Do linear maps preserve norm ordering?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Say if $A$ is a linear mapping between normed spaces $U\to V$, and if the norm of $x$ is less than the norm of $y$ in $U$, is it the case that the norm of $Ax$ is less than the norm of $Ay$ in $V$? I know this is true for isometries, but what about any linear maps?

If this is not true for any linear mapping, then is it true for linear operators (mapping from a space to itself)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be the linear operator defined by$$ T(x,y) = (x,0)$$
then $ \|(0,2)\| > \|(1,0)\|$ but $0=\|T(0,2)\|<\|T(1,0)\|=\|(1,0)\|$.

You might object that $T$ is not invertible so not "really an operator mapping from  $\mathbb R^2$ to itself". In which case you can consider
$$ T(x,y) = (2x,y)$$
Then $\|(0,3)\|>\|(2,0)\|$ but $3=\|T(0,3)\|<\|T(2,0)\|=4$. So really, the order can flip the moment you have two eigenvalues with different magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Such an $A$ is necessarily a scalar multiple of an isometry.

Suppose $A:U\to V$ is a linear map such that $\|Ax\|<\|Ay\|$ whenever $\|x\|<\|y\|$. (I use the same symbol $\|\cdot\|$ to denote the *two* different norms on $U$ and $V$. This should not cause any confusion.)

Then we must have $\|Ax\|\le\|Ay\|$ whenever $\|x\|\le\|y\|$. For, only one of the three possibilities
$\|x\|<\|y\|,\,x=y=0$ or $\|x\|=\|y\|\ne0$ is true.

- If $\|x\|<\|y\|$, then $\|Ax\|<\|Ay\|$ and hence $\|Ax\|\le\|Ay\|$.
- If $x=y=0$, then $Ax=Ay=0$ and hence $\|Ax\|\le\|Ay\|$.
- If $\|x\|=\|y\|\ne0$, then $\|(1-\frac1n)x\|=(1-\frac1n)\|x\|<\|y\|$ for every positive integer $n$. Therefore $(1-\frac1n)\|Ax\|=\|A\left((1-\frac1n)\right)x\|<\|Ay\|$. Let $n\to+\infty$, we obtain $\|Ax\|\le\|Ay\|$.

In turn, we also have $\|Ax\|=\|Ay\|$ whenever $\|x\|=\|y\|$, because $\|x\|=\|y\|$ implies that $\|x\|\le\|y\|$ and $\|y\|\le\|x\|$, and by the result from last paragraph, we obtain $\|Ax\|\le\|Ay\|$ and $\|Ay\|\le\|Ax\|$.

It follows that there exists a constant $c$ such that $\|Ax\|=c\|x\|$ for all $x\in U$. This is clearly true when $U=0$. Suppose $U\ne0$. Pick a unit vector $u$ from $U$ and let $\|Au\|=c$. For every nonzero vector $x\in U$, we have $\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=\|u\|$ and hence $\left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=\|Au\|=c$. Therefore $\|Ax\|=\|x\|\left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=c\|x\|$. The equality $\|Ax\|=c\|x\|$ is also satisfied by $x=0$. Hence it is true over the whole space $U$, i.e. $A$ is $c$ times an isometry.

Answer (score 0):

Another counterexample that one can "see" geometrically:  orthogonal basis

$$\left(\vec{i}=\binom{2}{0},\vec{j}=\binom{0}{1}\right) \ \text{with} \ \| \vec{i}\| > \| \vec{j}\|$$

that becomes, by applying the $\pi/2$ rotation $R$:

$$\left(R\vec{i}=\binom{0}{2},R\vec{j}=\binom{-1}{ \ \ 0}\right)  \ \text{with} \ \|R \vec{i}\| < \| R\vec{j}\|$$